# Remove details from loaded OSM-layer? - Openlayers-3

Tags: openlayers, layers

I have created a tile server with help from [this guide](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/).
Sadly I still have no software to actually create the tiles and because of that I load in a online map (HOT) from OSM via Openlayers:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: [],
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM({layer:'hot'})
        }), ... etc
```

Is it possible to hide details from this source?

I will eventually start using the data from my tile-server but I'm on a short deadline, so I'd like to evaluate my options...

Answer (score 1):

Attribution is a default control when initialising your map. So you need to disable it. Like so:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }),
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM({layer:'hot'})
        }), ... etc
```